# OS X: run multiple instances of desktop emacs app with a separate dot file for each

Tags: init-file, osx

Is it possible to run Emacs.app with ~/.emacs.d/init.el and Emacs2.app with another init.el file that's placed somewhere else? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Inside the Emacs.app folder is an executable that you can run directly, with some command line flags:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --no-init-file --load /my/other/init2.el
```

(Your Emacs.app may be in a different folder)

Comment: thanks, it worked, but is it impossible to run the second one always with the second init.el file whenever I just double click the Emacs2.app on the Dock, by changing some files within the app's package contents?

Comment: I don't know how to do that but you might take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items/271697#271697)